# Declaring resolution-aware image assets is not working in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, assets

I'm developing flutter application. I want to apply images in my app, but it is not working.
Of course, I applied the same as the guide. Only the base image is being referenced.
Please let me know how resolve this problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]